# Capturing the submatches after the second instance of a string variable

Tags: excel, regex, vba

How would one capture two numeric submatches after the second instance of a string/number?

I have a # that changes from .txt file to .txt file. It is captured in a variable called "Total" which I declared as a string. The string contains numbers, in the format of 123, 456,789.23 or 123, 456.01. This number appears about 3 times within the .txt file, and I have written a RegEx pattern that is able to capture the first instance of this number and its submatches.

```
regex.Pattern =  Total & "\s*([\d+\.\d*])\s*([\d+\.\d*])\s*"
```

The .txt file portion I am trying to capture may appear as

```
123,456,789.38 

2.180
 
251.517
```

OR

```
123,456,789.38  2.180  251.517
```

I want to capture 2.180 and 251.517.

The first instance includes the words "Number of: " in front of it, and I tried to make the pattern avert from the ":" before it by writing:

```
regex.Pattern = "[^:\s]" & Total & "\s*([\d+\.\d*])\s*([\d+\.\d*])\s*"
```

It still picks up this first instance and the numbers after that first instance. The second instance does not have any defining words before it, just a blank line such as the one below:

```
123,456,789.38 

2.180 

251.517
```

Additional information:

```vb
    Dim regex As Object: Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    regex.Pattern =  Total & "\s*([\d+\.\d*])\s*([\d+\.\d*])\s*"
    Dim MCS As Object
    Set MCS = regex.Execute(myText)
    Dim Total As String: Total = MCS(0).submatches(0)
    Dim submatch1 As String: submatch1 = MCS(0).Submatches(1)
    Dim submatch2 As String: submatch2 = MCS(0).Submatches(2)
```

where `mytext` is the contents of the .txt file entirely as a string.

There are also words and numbers between the different instances of the variable "Total", such as

```
Number of: 123,456,789.38

Text Here Text Here

Number Here

123,456,789.38

2.180

251.517
```

I am also not sure how much/many text/numbers there will be between the first two instances of 123,456,789.38, so I am trying to think of how to work this to be flexible.

When I mention second instance, I mean that the number 123,456,789.38 (which is the variable named "Total") appears three times in the document. I want to capture the two submatches that appear after that number. However, since there are three times it appears, I want to capture the two submatches that appear after the second time that `123,456,789.38` pops up.

Link to the text file.
https://regex101.com/r/4hPtY3/6

Output:

```
submatch1 = 2.180
submatch2 = 251.517
```

Currently, it is capturing

```
submatch1 = 97
submatch2 = 5
```

with the pattern:

```vb
regex.Pattern = Replace(Total, ".", "\.") & "\s*([.\d]+)\s*([.\d]+)"
```

Comment: You corrupted the number matching pattern by putting `[` and `]` around it, `[\d+\.\d*]` onlymatches a single digit, `+`, `.` or `*` char. Use `\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?` to match numbers. Please post the [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is not quite clear now what exact text you have and what exact pattern you apply.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, please see the edits within the post, and thank you very much for your explanation, I see why it was only picking up one number now!

Comment: It is still a bit hard to come up with something working. What is exactly in `Total` variable?  Why do you initialize it after using? If your `Total` hold the "Number" word, see how it could work - `^(?:[\s\S]*?Number){2}\D+(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/9N3Qvn/1/)). If it does not work, please edit the regex fiddle and share the updated link with comments on what does not work.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, the Total variable comes from another RegEx pattern where it picks up the first number after the words "Number of:"

Dim reg2 As Object: Set reg2 = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    reg2.Pattern = "Number of:\s*[\$?](\d+[\,\.\d]*)\s*"
        Set MCS = reg2.Execute(myText)
         Total = MCS(0).Submatches(0)

It changes from .txt file to .txt file.

Comment: So, if you use `regex.Pattern = "^(?:[\s\S]*?" & Total & "){2}\D+(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)"`, does it work now?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, it gives me an "Invalid Procedure or Call" error.

Comment: So, it would look like https://regex101.com/r/9N3Qvn/2. You must have copied / pasted my suggestion incorrectly, the declaration is good.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, thank you for your help again. I've tried it multiple times but to no avail. I've posted a sample test file in this link here for clarification. 

https://regex101.com/r/4hPtY3/3

Comment: Daria, please edit the question to make it clear. Do not describe everything you do, only provide 1) the exact *text* you have now to handle, 2) exact expected output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I have edited the post based off your suggestions. Please see above.

Comment: Daria, I have again used [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776611/vba-regex-capturing-the-submatches-after-the-second-instance-of-a-variable-str?noredirect=1#comment114532680_64776611) and [it works](https://regex101.com/r/4hPtY3/7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```vb
regex.Pattern = "^(?:[\s\S]*?" & Replace(Total, ".", "\.") & "){2}\D+([.\d]+)\s*([.\d]+)"
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4hPtY3/7) where you can see that

[image]

As expected.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[\s\S]*?123,456\.78){2}` - two occurrences of any 0+ chars as few as possible and then `123,456.78` string
- `\D+` - 1 or more non-digit chars
- `([.\d]+)` - Group 1: one or more dots or digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([.\d]+)` - Group 2: one or more dots or digits.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I fiddled around with my Total variable and your suggestion worked! Thank you again for your help, looks like it was an issue of what value the variable was holding.